# Get different system fonts in tomcat than in standalone java app

Tags: java, tomcat, fonts

I run the following code in both a simple class with a main function as well as in a servlet/jsp on tomcat.

```
Font fonts[] = ge.getAllFonts();
int j = fonts.length;
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++ ) {
  System.out.println(fonts[i].getFamily());
}
```

The list returned is not the same for both cases. Specifically, a .otf font is not listed in tomcat, but is listed in standalone. Can anyone find a reason? A lead?

Details
- Running both cases on the same headless server
- Ubuntu Linux 10.04
- OpenJDK 1.6.0_20
- Tomcat 6.0.24
- I've run the standalone version with the same VM parameters as tomcat is started

Thanks!
Marc

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but are you sure you are using the same GraphicsEnvironment instance? Also I would guess if you were running the two snippets with different permissions (ie tomcat vs local user) you might find that some fonts don't have the right access.

Comment: @mlathe makes some good points. Must admit I just tried on my Windows pc with Eclipse and Pluto server (Tomcat underneath), and they reported the same fonts.

Comment: @mlathe you nailed it! Different user rights on the font files. Should have started with that... Post your solution and I'll flag it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark, but are you sure you are using the same GraphicsEnvironment instance? Also I would guess if you were running the two snippets with different permissions (ie tomcat vs local user) you might find that some fonts don't have the right access.

Comment: The solution was the different permissions of the tomcat versus local user